# Mathematica says this Gaussian integral does not converge

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Mathematica does not recognize this special case of Gaussian integral.

Integrate[exp(-Q^2-(v^2R^2/16/a^2/Q^2)), {Q, R/(4at)^(1/2), Infinity}, Assumptions -> a >= 0 && t >= 0 && R >= 0 && v >= 0]

This should be solved since I say the solution using the erf(x) function in the literature.

Comment: The exponential function in Mathematica is not `exp(arg)` but `Exp[arg]` (note the capitalization and square brackets.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Integrate[
 Exp[-Q^2 - (v^2 R^2/16/a^2/Q^2)], {Q, R/(4 a t)^(1/2), Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> a >= 0 && t >= 0 && R >= 0 && v >= 0]
```

$$\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\pi } e^{-\frac{R v}{2 a}} \left(e^{\frac{R v}{a}} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{R+t v}{2 \sqrt{a t}}\right)+\text{erfc}\left(\frac{R-t v}{2 \sqrt{a t}}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me how you got the answer?

Comment: `Exp[...]` is correct syntax as Michael Seifert points out in the comments. `at` will be considered a variable, so I used a space in between.

Comment: I have copied your solution but Mathemetica does not provide the answer

Comment: @MazAnsari, try restarting the kernel or use ``Clear["Global`*"]``. Otherwise, let us know which version of Mathematica you're using.

Comment: @Domen thanks. Also I would advise the OP not to use upper case letters in Mathematica.  `$Version` is the command for getting the version.

Comment: I am using version 12.3.

Comment: Integrate[
 Exp[-q^2 - (v^2 r^2/16/a^2/q^2) - (u^2 r^2/16/a^2/q^2)], {q, 
  r/(4 a t)^(1/2), Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> a >= 0 && u >= 0 && t >= 0 && r >= 0 && v >= 0]

Could you please run this? @Syed

Comment: Not in its current form, but I see that this question has been answered.